# Как анимацию html превратить в видео на стороне сервера?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть html элемент DIV в котором есть svg и элементы html с анимацией JS(GSAP). Каким образом можно эту анимацию превратить в видео? Особенно интересно как можно этот html контейнер с анимацией передать на серверную сторону, где уже превращать в видео, так как проводить создание видео на клиенте не очень хорошее занятие.
Может кто то сталкивался с такой задачей и знает как её решить, или возможно есть идеи или варианты решения данной задачи?

Comment: Пример анимации был бы очень кстати.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну например вот такая анимация на js https://codepen.io/maciekmp/pen/tdoef

на самом деле анимация тут может быть любая, суть вопроса тут больше каким образом любая js анимация html объектов может быть преобразована в видео на стороне сервера. Т.е. сама анимация на фронт енд, а сборка и конвертация на бэкенде. Есть даже веб-сервисы (конструкторы видео для соц сетей) где так же каким то образом html анимация потом отправляется на сервер и там собирается в видео. Как это делает очень хотелось бы понять :)

Comment: Пример надо бы добавить в сам вопрос. Так же, неплохо было бы указать где можно посмотреть *Есть даже веб-сервисы (конструкторы видео для соц сетей) где так же каким то образом html анимация потом отправляется на сервер и там собирается в видео*